# How do i validate XML against a schema (php or perl or possible C++)

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

I need to take in XML and validate it against a schema file. Afterward i must call a function based on the command (example updateContactList). What is the best way to do this? I am worried about validating the XML (and report errors) and i have no idea what is the best way to put the data into a function to run

-edit- NOTE: By validating the schema i need to validate the (regex) pattern. It would be great if i can call a function with the XML and schema and have it return false + error msg or true

Comment: What do you mean regex pattern? You should not be trying to validate XML against regular expressions.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you mean by regex pattern? The most common way to validate an XML document is trough an [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)). You can use [`DomDocument->schemaValidate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) for this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($tempFile);
$doc->schemaValidate('schema.xsd');
```

There is also the corresponding [`DomDocument->relaxNGValidate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.relaxngvalidate.php) for validating against the lesser used [RelaxNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) schema.

You may also want to use the [error-handler functions for libxml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php), if you plan on capturing the errors and doing something about them, rather than just validate true or false. In essence, call `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before loading and validating the document, and use `libxml_get_errors` and `display_xml_error` to fetch the errors.